# O-notation and some math

Tags: algorithm, math

Just started learning algorithms. So the exercise is to find if statement is always/sometimes true or false. Em, where does my logic fails here?

```
f(n) != O(g(n)) and g(n) != O(f(n))
```

O-notation is `0 <= f(n) <= cg(n)` where `c` is some constant. So not equal here means:

```
f(n) > cg(n) and g(n) > cf(n)
```

If `f(n) = g(n) = 1`, and let's say `c = 1/2`:

```
1 > (1/2)*1 and 1 > (1/2)*1
```

So it is true in this case. But the book says it's false in this particular case. What part do I misunderstand?

Comment: I am not seeing the link between Big-O notation and trying to prove if a statement is always/sometimes true or false.  Can you provide a little more information?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Uh, not sure what else can I provide. Seem enough for me. `f(n), g(n)` - linear functions, `O(f(n))` - Big-O notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big-O is not `0 <= f(n) <= c g(n)` for *some* constant, per se.  It's that there exists a number *c* such that the relation holds for "large enough" values of *n*. (This is the "asymptotic" that we refer to when we call Big-O an asymptotic notation, the other common ones being Big-Theta and Big-Omega.)

For example, let's say there's an algorithm that operates on some data structure with `n` elements, and takes `3n^2 + 7n + 18` steps.  Call this `f(n)`.  We say that the Big-O of this expression is `O(n^2)` because there exists a constant (in this case anything larger than 3) such that for all "large enough" values of `n`, `f(n) <= c n^2`.

Comment: but from the definition - 'if there are positive constants c and n0 such that'... http://chuck.ferzle.com/Notes/Notes/AlgorithmAnalysis/AsymptoticHandout.pdf

Comment: Precisely.  If there exist any positive constants `c` and `n0`.  So in your example, 1/2 does not satisfy for `c`, but there exists another constant that would.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now (a little piece of it, to be honest, but it's a learning curve, huh). Thank you!